# Обработка массивов assembler masm

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, ассемблер, masm32

Программа выполняет следующую задачу: 
Даны массивы A и B из 16 байтов.Составить из элементов с
одинаковыми номерами слово (элемент из B — старший байт).Если это слово не делится на 3, то поместить адрес (смещение) этого элемента в массив C и сосчитать их количество(числа беззнаковые).

```
int main()
{
char A[16], B[16];
short int B1[16];
char C[16], C1[16];
int i = 0, j = 0, z = 0;
int k = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    A[i] = i;     // чтобы не вводить 32 числа, сгенерирую их
    B[i] = i + 1;
}
__asm
{
    xor eax, eax
    xor edx, edx
    xor ebx, ebx

    mov cl, 0

    lea esi, A
    lea edi, B
    //lea esp, C

    G : xor edx, edx
        cmp cl, 0
        je K
        cmp cl, 16
        je H

        lea esi, [esi + 1]
        lea edi, [edi + 1]


    K:  mov bl, 10h
        mov al, [esi] //esi = a
        cmp al, 10
        jge P
        mul bl
        mov ah, [edi] //edi = b
        shr eax, 4
        jmp N


    P : mov ah, [edi] //edi = A


    N : mov ebx, 3
        div bx
        cmp dx, 0
        je T


        xor edx, edx
        mov edx, k
        mov byte ptr[C + edx], cl
        inc k

    T : inc cl
        jmp G


    H : xor ecx, ecx
        mov ecx, k
        mov C[ecx], 0

}
printf("Asm result:\n");
printf("k = %hd\n", k);
printf("%d ", (int)C[0]);
if (C[0] == '\0') {
    C[0] = 48;
}

for (i = 1; i < strlen(C); i++) {
    printf("%d ", (int)C[i]);
}
getch();

return 0;
}
```

Ассемблерную вставку, можно считать, написали за меня. Я понимаю каждую строку отдельно, но не понимаю смысл кода в целом. Например, выяснилось, что обход массива начинается с конца. Как можно представить алгоритм работы такой вставки? Рисовать блок-схему пытался, получилась глупость какая-то.